# Is Chinese language influenced by sanskrit and vice versa?

Tags: history

India and China are neighboring countries, in ancient India sanskrit was spoken and in ancient China Chinese was spoken.

So could these two languages have influenced each other in any way.

Comment: Mmm... looks like the Himalayas, the world's highest mountain range, is between the two countries. I can't imagine a ton of activities up there on the top of the world.

Comment: From where do you get the idea? Just because they are neighbors? Religion-wise, China had been influenced by India, but I doubt there was any other similarity between the two oldest civilizations.

Comment: @r13 It is believed to be a borrowing from Middle Persian, and some have traced it further back to Sanskrit.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_China#:~:text=It%20is%20believed%20to%20be,state%20for%20many%20centuries%20 prior. If the word China can from sanskrit why not other words

Comment: I think this question should be posted on the "History" forum. The wiki source is unconvincing, as China wasn't a unified country prior to the Qin dynasty (286-225 BC), I strongly believe, 中国 was named from then and after by the foreigners.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah a lot of phrases in China were translated from Buddhism scripts written in Sanskrit.

The most famous one we use everyday is [刹那](https://zh.m.wikipedia.org/zh-hans/%E5%88%B9%E9%82%A3)

Even the name [佛](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BD%9B) itself is from Sanskrit.

Comment: Thanks for the answer